# ng-repeat does not show object attributes

Tags: angularjs

I have this html:

```
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">

            <h1> {{store.products.name}} </h1>
            <h2> {{store.products.price}} </h2>
            <p> {{store.products.description}} </p>
            <p/>
            <button>Add to Cart </button>       
    </div>
</body>
```

And this JavaScript (that is **app.js**):

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('store', [ ]); 
app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.products = gems;

});
var gems = [
    {
        name: 'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: 'Some gems have hidden qualities beyond their luster, beyond their shine... Dodeca is one of those gems.',
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Pentagonal Gem',
        price: 5.95,
        description: 'You will feel right at home.',
        canPurchase: true,
        soldOut: false
    }
]; })();
```

When I launch the html in a browser, it shows an "Add to Cart" button for both gems, but the **name**, **price**, and **description** do not display.
When I add the following line to the html, it correctly displays the price for the first gem:

```
<h2> {{store.products[0].price}} </h2>
```

So apparently I'm referencing the products correctly.

I have no idea why the attributes are not displaying otherwise.

Comment: User `product` inside your ng-repeat like `{{product.name}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to it as `product`.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
        <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
        <h2> {{product.price}} </h2>
        <p> {{product.description}} </p>
        <p/>
        <button>Add to Cart </button>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`store.products` is an array of objects you just can't access like it. if you want to access the properties of the current product you have to do like below,

```
 <div ng-repeat="product in products">
            <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
            <h2> {{product.price}} </h2>
            <p> {{product.description}} </p>
            <p/>
            <button>Add to Cart </button>       
  </div>
```

Also your code does not get compiled, here is the working [`Application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/myg4xyqr/2/)